# MySQL table column description help needed

Tags: php, mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
)
```

Please explain me what is doing **UNIQUE KEY 'username' (username')** statement in the example above and why **('username')** is written once again?

Comment: This would make some sense if you had a "username" column in your table. Don't you get any error message when trying to execute this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNIQUE_KEY line is creating a unique index called 'username' on the column 'username'. A unique index allows only a single record to have a specific value. This is useful on rows like usernames because it prevents two users from being created with the same username.

However, I think you would get an error if you ran this because you have not defined a column called username.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
)
```

Comment: Ok, but I use "id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY" instead of "`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)". SO can't we define a UNIQUE KEY in one line?

Comment: You can create an index "inline" but that is a less common syntax.

Comment: In that case I should wite "`username` varchar(50) UNIQUE KEY"?

Comment: I believe it would be username varchar(50) UNIQUE but I am not 100% sure. There is not a lot of official documentation for that specific syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply the format MySQL's [CREATE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) expects. If you look at the syntax in detail, you'll see...

```
UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
  [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
  [index_option] ...
```

In other words, you're using an index_name of "username" which uses the "username" field/column. This might seem odd, but if you were using a compound key, you'd might have a definition something like...

```
UNIQUE KEY duplicate_lock (user_email, user_name)
```

...so you'd have different index name and column portions of the definition.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not cleat to me what is index_name?

Comment: index_name is the name that the index is referred to in queries if you want to explicitly tell MySQL which index to use. This is commonly done when the index includes multiple columns and the query is rather complex.